# How to approach subscriptions in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphcool

I need some help to figure out what is a general approach on subscriptions and real-time updating. I have a React Native app and using Apollo and Graphcool service as a backend.

There are a couple scenarios where user looking at the app receives a push notification that something has changed. Naturally, the screen data should get updated as well. Subscriptions are an obvious candidate for that job and I got it working essentially.

I have a subscription like this which works just fine on its own (used to position player avatars on google map).

```graphql
subscription PlayerMap($gameId: ID) {
  Game(filter: { mutation_in: [CREATED, UPDATED], node: { id: $gameId } }) {
    node {
      players {
        id
        character {
          id
          name
        }
        user {
          id
          latitude
          longitude
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then there is a different app screen executing a mutation `createPlayer` along with `refetchQueries` from Apollo (for simplicity) which runs this query to update stuff.

```graphql
query GameCharacters($gameId: ID!) {
  Game(id: $gameId) {
    players {
      id
      character {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when this completes, the subscription query (that is still active on another screen) also gets updated but for some reason whole `Game` node is missing in `data` object.

For handling subscriptions, I have a component like this.

```js
class Subscriber extends Component<void, Props, void> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscribe()
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps({ data, shouldResubscribe }) {
    if (this.unsubscribe) {
      if (shouldResubscribe && shouldResubscribe(data, this.props.data) !== true) {
        return
      }
      this.unsubscribe()
    }
    this.subscribe()
  }
  subscribe() {
    const { data, query, variables } = this.props
    this.unsubscribe = data.subscribeToMore({
      document: query,
      variables,
    })
  }
  unsubscribe: ?Function = null
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.props.data)
  }
}
```

I can then use it simply like this with render prop pattern.

```js
const OrgMapScreen = ({ gameId, data: initialData }: Props) => (
  <Subscriber
    data={initialData}
    query={OrgMapSubscription}
    variables={{ gameId }}
    shouldResubscribe={(nextData, prevData) => nextData.Game !== prevData.Game}
  >
    {({ Game }) => {
      const markers = Game.players.map(makePlayerMarker)
      return <MapScreen mapProps={{ markers }} />
    }}
  </Subscriber>
)
```

I am rather confused why is that happening. Is there some recommended way how to handle stuff like that? Perhaps instead of `refetchQueries` I should set up another subscription for `GameCharacters` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess (not an Apollo expert), I would guess it has to do with either the wrong `document` input in your `subscribeToMore` (it seems like you're using the query and not the subscription as the parameter?) or a missing `updateQuery` in `subscribeToMore`, which returns the updated data.

In our case, we have an `orderChanged` subscription that listens to changes on an `Order`. When we receive an update, we want to replace the order in our `orders` query with the updated order. We do so in the `updateQuery` function in `subscribeToMore` (apologies for typos, this is not an exact copy-paste):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.data.subscribeToMore({
    document: OrderSubscription,
    variables: {
      range: [0, 25]
    },
    updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData, }) => {
      // If no subscription data is passed, just return the previous
      // result from the initial `orders` query
      if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev

      // get the data for the updated order from the subscription 
      const updatedOrder = subscriptionData.data.orderChanged

      // find the index of the updated order from within the existing 
      // array of orders from the `orders` query
      const existingOrderIndex = prev.orders.findIndex(order => (order.id === updatedOrder.id))

      // guard for missing data
      if (existingOrderIndex) {
        // replace the old order with the updated order
        prev[existingOrderIndex] = updatedOrder
        // return orders with new, updated data
        return prev
      }

      return prev
    },
  })
}
```

If you could provide me with a minimum viable repo, I'd be happy to work through it with you. I spent much of last week working through subscriptions :)

Comment: Yeah turns out that `updateQuery` is kinda necessary. I don't know why I got an impression that Apollo would crawl the result on its own and update store based on types and `dataIdFromObject`. Oh well. Had to use `immutable-helper` for a deeply nested structure like mine, but it seems to be working now. Thanks